# Text styles in Davinci Resolve

Tags: davinci-resolve

Is it somehow possible to reuse text styles in Davinci Resolve (and Fusion)?
Each text node by default has OpenSans font, which does not work for me when I want to insert Japanese text (e.g. I want to switch the font to Noto Sans JP, adjust the size a bit etc.) Basically, like I would use character styles in Word, Libreoffice, Affinity Publisher etc, to develop a kind of custom stylesheet for my videos.

I know that I can create a custom title template which holds this Text+ node in Fusion, and just include it in the timeline. Unfortunately, then I cannot use any of the normal templates available (let's say a call out template). Or I would need to customize every one of these and save in a power bin.

I guess my main options are currently just to note in a separate text file the custom options and then just apply it manually? This seems really ugly though...

Are there maybe any better options?